# Cloning a git repo in a task by providing authentication

Tags: gradle

I want to clone a private repository in my system. I am able to clone a **public** repo using:

```
def myrepo = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.clone(dir:'', uri:'')
```

but in case of a private repo, I need to provide credentials to clone. I have gone through this [link](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/org/ajoberstar/grgit/auth/AuthConfig.html), but the properties given here like `Force`, `Hardcoded` are not available in my gradle. So, I am not able to make use of the properties given here.

The following properties are available for me:

```
org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.AuthConfig.FORCE_OPTION
org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.AuthConfig.USERNAME_OPTION
org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.AuthConfig.PASSWORD_OPTION
```

and if I give any value to these, I get error *Cannot assign value to final fields*
Can anybody help with the authentication part?

I am using dependency `org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.3.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided clearly states that **system properties** need to be used to pass appropriate settings.

So you need to run gradle passing all the properties via command line. Assume this is `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
     classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.3.0'
   }
}

task cloneRepo << {
   org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.clone(dir: '', uri: '<link to private repo>')
}
```

Run it with:

```
gradle cloneRepo -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.username=your_username -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.password=your_pass -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.force=sshagent
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped :) But one more thing, I am able to clone the repository but it comes with a red mark(that specifies that code has been changed locally), I have no idea why it isn't green. Any idea?

Comment: Run `git status` to verify what has been changed.

Comment: Actually, I am running all the command through windows command prompt. How can I run this task there?

Comment: Hi, I have another doubt. In order to create a tag for the same repo, as per the documentation link provided ,I have added the below lines of code :C:\Users\Byteorigin\AndroidStudioProjects\Test_task>gradlew cloneTest -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.hardcoded=true -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.username=' '-Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.password='' -Dorg.ajobertar.grgit.tag.add(name: 'new-Tag', message: 'Somme Msgggg!!').  This should work, right?